# CSS Same property declaration is not working

Tags: css

**I have this HTML layout:**

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>AmarCourse</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="post">
            <article>
                <h2>My First Article</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        </aside>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Copyright</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <address>Dhanmondi 15 no, Dhanmondi, Dhaka-1209.</address>
        <p>All rights reserverd</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**Now, I am using the following CSS for the footer and header:**

```
header nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}

footer nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can see that both header and footer hash the same css property that's why I am writing this code:

```
header,
footer nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**But It's showing me:**

[image]

**Should be show**

[image]

Comment: Oh, Updating my question.

Comment: if possible provide the codesandbox link

Comment: @SwarajGandhi Please don’t encourage external resources. Stack Exchange sites have a Stack Snippet button for this purpose. See [How to create Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Comment: cool, will keep that in mind

Comment: They are not the same. The header has `justify-content: space-around;` but the footer has it as `justify-content: center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you are selecting only the header element and not the nav and the li inside it.

Please try the below:

```
header nav ul,
footer nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code will work only for the footer but I want the header area too.

Comment: It will work for both header and footer, please give it a try and let me know. I have made an update, I could have missed it while pasting

Comment: Oh, Yes, why we need to write like this?

Comment: If it is pure CSS, you will need to specify the actual element, in your case, you only selected the header and not the items inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me, with one change:

In the original CSS, `header` and `footer nav ul` have different `justify-content` attributes. Make sure you are using the correct selectors, as Arjun said, but you will need to leave the `justify-content: center;` for `header`.

It's probably best you leave it as it was, because that will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like desplay flex for `header` is worth. Because you wants Logo be up to the nav so just add to header `flex-direction:column; justify-content:center;` align-items is worth - delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

```
header,
footer nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here you select only the header. You should be able to use this code for it to work.

```
header nav ul, 
footer nav ul 
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```